# Add toomanyattempts in my login controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, lockout

I need to add the functionality that toomanyloginattempts with my login . now its not working. Iam using Laravel Framework 5.1.45 (LTS). 
The code that i used is mentioned below.
My controller function is

```
    <?php
    use App\Libraries\SessionHelper;
    use App\Libraries\ConfigUtils;
    use App\Libraries\GeneralLib;
    use App\Models\OrgSettings;
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
    use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

    class LoginController extends Controller {
     use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

      public function doLogin() {
        $email = Input::get('email');
        $pass = Input::get('password');
        $candidate_login_user = User::getUserByEmail($email);
        $data = User::authenticate($email, $pass);
        if (empty($data)) {
          User::logFailedAuthentication($email, $candidate_login_user->organization);
          Session::flash('error', "Incorrect email or password.");
          return Redirect::to('/login');
        }

    }
```

my  view page is as follows

```
    <form action="login" method="post">
                    <div class="body bg-gray">
                       <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <strong >Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif

                        <?php
                            Session::forget('error');
                            Session::forget('success');
                        ?>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="email"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" name="password"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="password"/>
                        </div>
```

Comment: "now its not working" - in what way? not authenticating, or not limiting attempts, or are you getting a 500 error, or a blank page? what are the random `=` signs at the bottom of your controller class?

Comment: toomany login attempts is not showing even after many failed logins. How can i achieve this?

Comment: i have added use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers; in controller and inside my class LoginController extends Controller {
    
use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;
   but not working

Comment: in the code that i mentioned above

Comment: Is the `doLogin` your own code? And that is the action you're routing to when the user submits the form?

Comment: yes doLogin is my custom function. i need to lockout the user after 5 failure attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're implementing your own login action it is not enough to just add the traits to your `LoginController` to implement throttling.

You need to be checking the `hasTooManyLoginAttempts` method from your `doLogin` action, and firing the lockout event yourself, if necessary.

```php
public function doLogin(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {
    if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
        $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

        return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
    }


    $email = Input::get('email');
    $pass = Input::get('password');
    $candidate_login_user = User::getUserByEmail($email);
    $data = User::authenticate($email, $pass);


    if (empty($data)) {
        User::logFailedAuthentication($email, $candidate_login_user->organization);
        Session::flash('error', "Incorrect email or password.");
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        return Redirect::to('/login');
    }
}
```

Altogether, I think you'd be better off simply using the built-in Auth controllers to handle your login (or at least using them as a starting point) rather than reimplement your own.

Comment: i have added this code . but error  message is not showing in the front end login.